# Windows 7 client - No permissions to manage Hyper-V server

Tags: virtualization, permissions, hyper-v, user-management

I am running Windows 7 ultimate and im trying to manage VM's on my Hyper-V server via the MMC.
I can connect to the machine, but I get the "You do not have the required permissions to complete this task. Please contact..." message.

I have used the [HVRemote](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote) script and ran all of the required commands on another Windows 7 machine on my network and it worked perfect, I do the same on my machine and I get the permissions error.

For now I have disabled the firewall on my machine and the server, and still nothing. Ive rebooted both machines.

How can I adjust the permissions here? Any ideas on why the other Windows 7 machine works flawless and Im getting the error?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1):

A coworker was running into this issue, and had to change a DCOM permission setting.  Walkthrough is [here](http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2008/08/07/hyper-v-why-does-hyper-v-manager-not-always-work-over-vpn-connection-access-denied-or-rpc-server-unavailable-errors.aspx), though the issue had nothing to do with VPN in our case, this still resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure you're running the Hyper-V manager mmc with credentials that have admin access to the hyper-v server(s)?  Try a "run as" by shift-right clicking on the manager icon.

Comment: I've tried this - run as administrator, and as my user account that has admin access and no luck